# Does launchOptions 'UIApplicationLaunchOptionsLocalNotificationKey' contain NSDictionary or UILocalNotification

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, notifications, uilocalnotification

OK, so i've read various articles on how to check the local notifications in didfinishlaunchingwith options. For example this NSHipster article claims that remote and local keys both contain an NSDictionary. http://nshipster.com/launch-options/

However, i tested and it contains a UILocalNotification, and some other articles says so as well.

So, i've looked around but not found any definitive answer. Is this an OS Version issue? Do different versions contain different objects, or what?

Pointers much appreciated.

EDIT:

From the NSHipster article:

"A local notification populates the launch options on UIApplicationLaunchOptionsLocalNotificationKey, which contains a payload with the same structure as a remote notification:

UIApplicationLaunchOptionsLocalNotificationKey: Indicates that a local notification is available for the app to process. The value of this key is an NSDictionary containing the payload of the local notification."

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to [Apple Documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/Chapters/IPhoneOSClientImp.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008194-CH103-SW4), the UIApplicationLaunchOptionsLocalNotificationKey will give you an **UILocalNotification** object.

> If the default action button is tapped (on a device running iOS), the
>   system launches the app and the app calls its delegate’s
>   application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions: method, passing in the
>   notification payload (for remote notifications) or the
>   local-notification object (for local notifications). Although
>   application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions: isn’t the best place to
>   handle the notification, getting the payload at this point gives you
>   the opportunity to start the update process before your handler method
>   is called.

Sample code from Apple Docs

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)app didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {

    UILocalNotification *localNotif =

    [launchOptions objectForKey:UIApplicationLaunchOptionsLocalNotificationKey];

    if (localNotif) {

        NSString *itemName = [localNotif.userInfo objectForKey:ToDoItemKey];

        [viewController displayItem:itemName];  // custom method

        app.applicationIconBadgeNumber = localNotif.applicationIconBadgeNumber-1;

    }

    [window addSubview:viewController.view];

    [window makeKeyAndVisible];

    return YES;

}
```

**Edit:** Update for `UIApplicationLaunchOptionsRemoteNotificationKey`

`UIApplicationLaunchOptionsRemoteNotificationKey`, returns NSDictionary with [notification payload](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/Chapters/TheNotificationPayload.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008194-CH107-SW1)

also from the apple doc

> The value of this key is the UILocalNotification object that was triggered. For additional information about handling local notifications, see the application:didReceiveLocalNotification: method.

[apple-doc-UIApplicationLaunchOptionsLocalNotificationKey](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiapplicationlaunchoptionslocalnotificationkey)

Note: **this key deprecated since iOS10.0**

Comment: Thanks. I looked at apples doc, but since so many tutorials etc. actually had NSDictionary for the local as well, i was wondering if it worked differently in older versions of IOS. Thanks.

Comment: Glad it's clarified :)

Comment: Right. I'm still a bit worried that so many articles states that the local key should contain an NSDictionary, like the NSHipster article i linked to. I edited my question to show the relevant quote. Do you have any idea why this is, if it's not different IOS versions?

Comment: I guess you ment to add the NSHipster quote to the question. I am removing it from the answer as it may confuse future readers.

Comment: No issues. Can't say why the article mentions that it gives you an NSDictionary. You can always report it as a correction in the article on their [GitHub repository](https://github.com/NSHipster/articles)

Answer (score 2):

The Options parameter in the `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:` is a dictionary, in which a `UILocalNotification` can be contained as value for the key `UIApplicationLaunchOptionsLocalNotificationKey`, as per the [UIApplicationDelegate](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIApplicationDelegate_Protocol/index.html#//apple_ref/doc/constant_group/Launch_Options_Keys).

This is different from Remote notifications, which is a `NSDictionary` containing the payload, and can be fetched with the  `UIApplicationLaunchOptionsRemoteNotificationKey` key.

> `UIApplicationLaunchOptionsRemoteNotificationKey`
>
> > The presence of this key indicates that a remote notification is available for the app to process. The value of this key is an NSDictionary containing the payload of the remote notification. See the description of application:didReceiveRemoteNotification: for further information about handling remote notifications.
>
> `UIApplicationLaunchOptionsLocalNotificationKey`
>
> > The presence of this key indicates that a local notification is available for the app to process. The value of this key is the UILocalNotification object that was triggered. For additional information about handling local notifications, see the application:didReceiveLocalNotification: method.

Comment: Yeah, i've read that too. I'm just wondering why several articles, like the one i link to (ive included a quote from it now in my question), say that the local key contains an NSDictionary. If not because different IOS versions, why? Was it different in the beta or something?

Comment: I understand the concern, as the Apple doc state `UILocalNotification` appears in iOS4 and Mattt at NSHipster is mentionning that same iOS version in his article. Can't remember anything about that from the iOS4 beta days, though.